# Error: feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0 when installing with conda?

Tags: python, conda

I set up a conda env like this:

```
conda create --name py36 -c conda-forge python=3.6
```

And then when I went to install OpenTargets, I get:

```
(py36) env_work:~$ conda install -c bioconda opentargets
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0

Your installed version is: 2.27
```

Could anyone explain why this would be the case? I also tried with python 3.8, and I checked the documentation which says it should work for python > 3.5?